# Anki doesn't start in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: anki

Anki doesn't start at all. I installed it using ubuntu software center.
Tried installing python, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have reinstall an older version of anki and it works for me: https://apps.ankiweb.net/downloads/archive/